# Big 0 of fibonacci number using scanl Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm trying to understand how a list that computes fibonacci is so fast in haskell.

The list definition is

```
fibs = 1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs

 1 :: (1: scanl (+) 1 fibs) !! 0
:1 :: (1: scanl (+) 1 fibs) !! 1
:1+(1 :: (1: scanl (+) 1 (1: scanl (+) 1 fibs)!!0)!!2
:2+(1 :: (1: scanl (+) 1 (1: scanl (+) 1 fibs))!!1)!!3
:3+(2 :: (1: scanl (+) 1 (1: scanl (+) 1 (1: scanl (+) 1 fibs)!!0)!!2)!!4
:5+(3 :: (1: scanl (+) 1 (1: scanl (+) 1 (1: scanl (+) 1 fibs)!!1)!!3)!!5
:8+(5 :: (1: scanl (+) 1 (1: scanl (+) 1 (1: scanl (+) 1 (1: scanl (+) 1 fibs)!!0)!!2)!!4)!!6
```

This is the best way I know how to expand the list definition in a way that gets my question across.

So my question is why does this list expand so fast?
I'm very hazy on how to calculate big-O these days but intuitively the way I expand it, it seems that the stack would grow astronomically huge with the way the function keeps expanding for each iteration of the fibonacci sequence. In fact, it looks to me that for every 3 numbers a new sub fibonacci sequence is created.

Yet, when I run the function it is very fast.
Wiki says it is an O(n) function.
https://wiki.haskell.org/The_Fibonacci_sequence#With_scanl

Is it that the compiler is doing special tricks so that it doesn't stupidly keep expanding the function like I do by hand?

Also, is there a special name for this type of recursion? I guess it's some type of tail-recursion, but I feel very fuzzy about this function.

Comment: In Haskell, when you say things like "so fast", you sort of have to qualify what you mean.  *evaluating* `fibs` is not "fast"...it literally takes an infinite amount of time!  It'll never end.  evaluating a specific item in the list, that's something you can talk about.  in this case you can manually expand `fibs` out to the index you want, and see what evaluations are necessary to evaluate it.

Comment: I meant it grows fast in Big-O. I did manually expand it in my example. That wouldn't have helped because as the answers seems to clarify below, the compiler is smart enough to not recompute fibs from start.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The definition of `scanl` is (almost equivalent to):

```
scanl           :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]
scanl f q ls    = q : (case ls of
                           []   -> []
                           x:xs -> scanl f (f q x) xs)
```

So `fibs` expands to:

```
  fibs
= 1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs
```

We've computed the head of `fibs` in memory, so `scanl` knows its `x` -- a `1`. Then `f q x` is `1 + 1 = 2`:

```
= 1 : (1 : scanl (+) 2 (tail fibs))
```

Now, we have computed the head of `tail fibs` in memory, so `scanl` can fetch another `x` -- the second `1`. Then `f q x` is `1 + 2 = 3`:

```
= 1 : (1 : (2 : scanl (+) 3 (tail $ tail fibs)))
```

The `2` we've just added to the list is simultaneously the head of the list `scanl` is accumulating down (currently `tail $ tail fibs`) -- we can retrieve it instantly!

The trick is that the computation of `fibs` doesn't restart from the first `1`. Instead, `scanl` can look down the very list it's used in, and find the values it needs just in time! (I write `tail $ tail fibs` etc., but as we step through the computation, nowhere does `scanl` need to access the entirety of `fibs` "from the top" -- in the recursive call the head is simply chopped off, and the tail conveniently starts at the value we just calculated, which is now ready to use immediately in the next step.)

Comment: Then it sounds like the compiler is smart enough to reuse the existing list it's building instead of starting all over like I'm doing it when I expand manually.